# Are arrays and objects with numeric properties equal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, deepequals

Can someone explain to me why the following is true:

```
let foo = { 
    A: [ 1, 2 ] 
}
let bar = {
   "A": {
      "0": "1",
      "1": "2"
   }
}
assert.deepEqual(foo, bar);
```

Comment: The comparisons made in that function must be `==` comparisons and not `===` comparisons. (confirmed; if you compare with `.deepStrictEqual()` the assertion would fail.

Comment: And yes arrays are objects with properties.

Comment: They're equal if your description of equality makes them equal. If your `deepEqual` function tells you they're equal, then that means it passes its equality test.

Comment: @Pointy I would rephrase it by saying that an array is an object where keys are indexes. I think I got this fact when I discovered that I could do `foo.A` and `foo['A']` which is the array notation.

Comment: @sjahan array indexes are just like ordinary object property names; they *look* like integers but they're interpreted as strings. There's absolutely no difference between the behavior of the `.` and `[ ]` operators with objects and arrays. The special thing about arrays is the `length` property, plus of course all the functions on the Array prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message) says:

> Only enumerable "own" properties are considered. The `assert.deepEqual()` implementation does not test the `[[Prototype]]` of objects or enumerable own `Symbol` properties. For such checks, consider using `assert.deepStrictEqual()` instead.

The `assert.deepStrictEqual()` function does check the prototype too, and

```
assert.deepStrictEqual(foo, bar);
```

will return false.